# UIAlertView buttonIndex not working

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I guess I'm missing something obvious. I have `UIAlertView` to get app review but I can't get the buttons to do anything. I've called the `UIAlertViewDelegate` in `my.h`, I also have anther `UIAlertview` which is just on an `IBAction btn` and that works fine although it just had cancel `btn`.

I tried giving `alert.tag = 1` but that never made any difference so I commented out my first `UIAlertview`, so I just have one alert, still no joy. I guess I am missing something simple.

I've also tried `alertview.cancelButtonIndex` or `alertview.firstOtherButtonIndex` instead of 0

```
    -(void)  alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {



    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"index 0 ");
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"index 1 ");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
        NSUserDefaults *rateApp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSInteger appLaunch = [ rateApp integerForKey:@"appLaunch"];
        appLaunch = 0 ;
        [rateApp setInteger: appLaunch forKey:@"appLaunch"];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        NSLog(@"index 2 ");
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad


{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //rate app  appLaunch == 5 || appLaunch ==10
    NSUserDefaults *rateApp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger appLaunch = [ rateApp integerForKey:@"appLaunch"];
    if (appLaunch == 1  ) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Like this app ?" message:@"Why not rate at the app store" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"No thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"Remind me later", nil];
      //  alert.tag = 1;
        [alert show];
        }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlertView's `delegate` should be `self` instead of `nil`, if you want to invoke its delegate method.

**Use this Code :**

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Like this app ?" 
                      message:@"Why not rate at the app store"                                        
                      delegate:self 
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"No thanks" 
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"Remind me later", nil];
```